# How to save state of my ImageView (favorite), On Closing the app the app flushes the favorite which user has saved before

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview

Can anyone suggest how to do it through firebase. means the state of the imageview is stored in the firebase.
The thing to note is the imageview is on recycler view adapter.

```
  public static  class menu1fragBlogViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder                                                                      
  {                                                                                                                                                 
                                                                                                                                                    
      View mView;                                                                                                                                   
      ImageView fav;                                                                                                                                
      public String simage,sname; //contains name and image from firebase                                                                                                                  
      public int sPriceSmall,sPriceMedium;//contains pricesmall and pricemedium from firebase                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                                                                                            
      final boolean[] state = {false};
      state=false;          
                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                                                    
      SessionManager sessionManager = new SessionManager(itemView.getContext());                                                                    
      HashMap<String, String> userDetails = sessionManager.getUsersDetailsFromSession();                                                            
      String phone = userDetails.get(SessionManager.KEY_PHONE);                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                              
      DatabaseReference dbfavs=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")                                                                 
              .child(phone).child("favourites");                                                                                                    
     


 public menu1fragBlogViewHolder(View itemView){                                                                                                
          super(itemView);                                                                                                                          
          mView=itemView;                                                                                                                           
          fav=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_fav);                                                                                       
                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                    
          fav.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {                                                                                       
              @Override                                                                                                                             
              public void onClick(View view) {                                                                                                      
                  



                    if(phone==null) {                                                                                                                 
                    Toast.makeText(mView.getContext(), "PLEASE LOGIN FIRST", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                                          
                      return;                                                                                                                       
                  }                                                                                                                                 

                  if(state[0] ==false){                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                                                    
                      fav.setImageResource(R.drawable.like_ic);                                                                                     
                      int position=getAdapterPosition();                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                    
                      dbfavs.child(String.valueOf(position)).child("name").setValue(sname);                                                         
                      dbfavs.child(String.valueOf(position)).child("image").setValue(simage);                                                       
                      dbfavs.child(String.valueOf(position)).child("PriceSmall").setValue(sPriceSmall);                                             
                      dbfavs.child(String.valueOf(position)).child("PriceMedium").setValue(sPriceMedium);                                           
                                                                                                                                                    
                                                                 
                                                                                                                                                    
                      state[0] =true;                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                                                    
                  }                                                                                                                                 
                                                                                                                                                    
                 else if(state[0]==true){                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                    
                      fav.setImageResource(R.drawable.dislike_ic);                                                                                  
                                                                                                                                                    
                      dbfavs.child(String.valueOf(getAdapterPosition())).removeValue();                                                             
                                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                    
                      state[0]=false;                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                                                    
                  }                                                                                                                                 
                                                                                                                                                    
              }                                                                                                                                     
          });                                                                                                                                       
      }
```

Comment: is it that you want to show the image based on the state of the image from the firebase ? Please clarify more what are you trying to do.

Comment: I have made a favorite button(which is an ImageView id=fav), which has a state=false. If the state is false then on clicking the fav the information of Pizza(name,image etc.) get stored in Firebase(in the new child(favorites)of user which have logged in) otherwise if state is true(already added to favorite),onclicking fav the pizza selected gets deleted. But when the application is closed, even if the pizza is added to favorite(state is true), on reopening it state=false.My question is how can I save the state of favorite so that if user already had added the pizza to favorites gets it saved.

Comment: i guess everytime you start the app there has to be a retrieve state function